# regex match user agent with and without some word

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

To differentiate a user-agent Mobile and a User Agent Tablet, i wrote regex like these :

For Mobile:

```
.+iPhone.+|.+Android.+Mobile.+
```

For Tablet:

```
.+iPad.+Mobile.+|.+Android.+[^Mobile].+
```

And try on these user agent for tablet:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
```

-> OK Tablet

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; Nexus 10 Build/JSS15Q) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2307.2 Safari/537.36
```

-> OK Tablet

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; GT-I9505 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.59 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

-> OKTablet and this is not a tablet...

The last one is considered like the others, but this is a user agent for a mobile and this is not what i want..

I need to write my regex with a pattern which considerate as valid a user-agent string containing Android but strictly not containing "Mobile"

an idea anyone ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you to identify tablet:

```
.+(?:iPad.+Mobile|Android(?!.+Mobile)).+
```

Negative character class i.e. `[^Mobile]` doesn't mean not a `Mobile`. It just negates individual characters. So `[^Mobile]` will match a single character that is not one of these character inside `[...]`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD8vJ8/1)

Comment: it works ! thank you ! i tried with (?!.) but certainly in a bad way.. thanks again !